# Wordpress subscribe.url not using base page

Tags: wordpress, civimail, subscribe, base-page

I'm setting up a mailing list in CiviCRM 4.7.14 and the latest Wordpress.  In Administer->System Settings->CMS Database Integration, I have the base page set to /civicrm.  Yet when a mailing list subscribe confirmation is sent, the subscribe.url token uses http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailing/confirm&reset=1&etc...

By default, the link goes to the standard Wordpress login screen.  If I change the URL manually in the browser to use /civicrm instead of /wp-admin/admin.php it processes the subscription.  Or if I log in, the admin.php link processes the subscription.

I understand the "base page" stuff has been evolving through recent versions.  I did upgrade this CiviCRM install from 4.6.x, so maybe there was a glitch with that.  Is there something I can do to correct things?  I tried changing the base page to something else, then back to /civicrm to reset things, but it didn't help.

I haven't tested the unsubscribeUrl token, but can do so if it would help with debugging.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/issues/27/

---

Old workarounds:

I tracked down the problem somewhat and opened an issue at the bug tracker.  I describe a code change which makes this work...but I don't know whether it's the best solution.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20053

UPDATE: I couldn't get that old fix to work any more after upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.21.  So I put in an Apache rule in my .htaccess file to redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/wp-admin/admin\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=civicrm/mailing/confirm
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /civicrm [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Same problem exists in 5.11.0, plus somewhere along the line, the confirmation link began url-encoding the slash characters, so I had to add a similar rule to the .htaccess except with q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Fconfirm